# Can we develop Tizen mobile apps using Javascript?

Tags: tizen

How can we develop Tizen mobile apps using javascript?
Are there any other languages that are used for developing Tizen mobile apps?

Comment: You can easily find that out at [the Tizen developer site](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/dev-guide/2.3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Srivathsava, you can develop a Mobile Web App, which will enable you to use HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript:

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/cover_page.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this:
https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/sample-web-applications